# Bootstrap button changes automatically its Border

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a gridview that first column is a templatefield where I set two linkbutton (class defined btn-primary bootstrap).

When the first linkbutton is clicked(lnk1), a modal window appears, in that moment the border of the button changes from 0.990 to 20 (sides) and 6 (top and bottom).

I tried to set the border to 1 through css class but it is not working.

Quite lost, so hoping you all can help me.
Cheers.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridView" CssClass="table-striped table-hover" runat="server" AllowPaging="False" DataKeyNames="code, value" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="function1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="function2" OnRowCommand="function3">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="100px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk1" runat="server" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval ("code") %>' CssClass="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="halflings-icon white zoom-in"></i>
                </asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnClose" runat="server" CommandName="close" CommandArgument='<%# Eval ("code") %>' CssClass="btn btn-danger" Visible='<%# ((DateTime?)Eval("date")).HasValue==false %>'>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Can you please reproduce your code into a pure css and html so that we can test it out

Comment: Hi @RakibulIslam, thanks for your response. Well, I am not using css at all, just bootstrap class as you can see. In the other hand, I won´t a html solution, have to be with asp elements, like I have in the code I posted. Cheers my friend.

Comment: Hi Elias, Just to be clear, if you're using Bootstrap you are using CSS all over the place. Also `LinkButton`s render as anchor tags and always cause a postback so how are you displaying a bootstrap modal?  Where is your relevant JS/JQ?

Comment: @fnostro. Thnaks for your reponse. Well, I know I have to use them... You can see the properties and elements with F12 in your browser. I mean I am not using pure CSS and pure HTML. Maybe, I could translate the bootstrap class to its CSS values and viceversa. But I can´t use solutions in pure HTML, besides I prefer to use just Bootstrap classes. Best regards Mate.